# Knockout Json data binding issue

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to bind Json data to the UI using knockout but I keep getting nothing binding in the UI. below is the link that I am trying bind a json data.Browser is not displaying any error. Can you help me what I am missing here?

http://plnkr.co/edit/z4aQ1bWnqjd8aTDeLOSP?p=preview

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <span data-bind="text: myTestData().length"></span>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: myTestData">
    <li data-bind="text: abc"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var test = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.abc = data.ABC;
        self.name = ko.observable(data.DDA.Name);
      }

      var viewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.myTestData = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.GetMyDyta = function() {
          var processedResults = ko.observableArray([]);
          $.each(myData, function(index, data) {
            processedResults.push(new test(data));
          });
          self.myTestData.pushAll(processedResults());
        }
      }

      var vm = new viewModel()
      vm.GetMyData;
      ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });

    var myData = [{
      "ABC": "ABC1234",
      "DDA": {
        "Name": "1234.5678",
        "Number": {
          "End": 1234,
          "Start": 5678
        }
      }
    }, {
      "ABC": "BSP1234",
      "DDA": {
        "Name": "1234.5678",
        "Number": {
          "End": 1234,
          "Start": 5678
        }
      }
    }]
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *do* have an error, because you misspelled `self.GetMtDyta`. Use your browser developer tools console to look for errors your code might have produced.

The second issue is that `myTestData` does not contain what you think it does: in `self.myTestData.push(processedResults())`, it seems that you want to append the new `test` objects to the array. What you are doing instead is appending the observable array itself to `myTestData`.

Try this instead:

```
self.GetMyData = function () {
    $.each(myData, function (index, data) {
        self.myTestData.push(new test(data));
    });
}
```

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v5aGfhjKas9WdUeQyp54?p)

A nice way to debug these kinds of problems is `ko.dataFor`:

[image]

- open the developer tools of your browser - preferably Firefox, Chrome or Safari
- go to the elements panel ("Inspector" in Firefox) and show the console (press "ESC")
- select the DOM element which you want know the Knockout binding for - in this case, our `<li>`
- in the console, enter `ko.dataFor($0)`. `$0` always refers to the currently selected element

As you can see, instead of the single object with a `abc` and an `dda` property we expected, we have an array with to elements - this is why the `text: abc` binding fails with the console error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return myTestData }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return abc }"
Message: abc is not defined
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin you're right of course - I did not test my answer and missed the second issue. I have amended the answer - thanks for the heads up!